# Any idea why my nav bar will not collapse in a small window?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have created a nav bar, and styled it my way. However, when I make the window small, and click in the right corner on the button, the nav bar extends all the options and that's it. Once I click on one of the options, it will not close i.e. it will not collapse back. What am I doing wrong? Ive been exploring with this for a while now and cannot see the mistake.

**Here is my code:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">      
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- use a responsive image option so this logo looks good on devices - recommend using something like retina.js -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">Test</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#/home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#/about">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#/services">What We Do</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#/example">Examples</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#/testimonials">Testimonials</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#/contact">Contact Us</a>
            </li>  
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

In my index.html, I link to the header.html which works fine, and the following styles:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**And the javascript:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h Try This.....I think your css not properly added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking the links doesn't automatically collapse/toggle the Bootstrap navbar. This is by design.

If you want them to close after click you can add this to the links..

`data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in"`

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/Ia4LLB8Yyp

You could also use jQuery like this..

```
$(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('a') ) {
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
});
```